# Column does not exists in outer join after alias

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a problem with the next SQL query (generated by sequelize ORM):

```
SELECT 
    "Publication".*, 
    "user"."id" AS "user.id"
FROM 
    (SELECT "Publication"."club_id" AS "clubId", "Publication"."user_id" AS "userId" FROM "publication" AS "Publication" WHERE ("Publication"."club_id" = '1')) AS "Publication" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_account" AS "user" ON "Publication"."user_id" = "user"."id";
```

The resulting error is:

> ERROR:  column Publication.user_id does not exist
>
> LINE 6:  LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_account" AS "user" ON "Publication"."...
>                                                            ^

My intuition of what is happening is that `"Publication"."user_id"` is being aliased as `userId`. Then, the query is being aliased as `"Publication"`(overwriting the label which was previously refering to the table). The left outer join tries to match new the `Publication` `user_id` property with `user.id`, but it is unable because now it is called `userId`.

Am I correctly understanding the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ERROR:  column **Publication.user_id** does not exist

Answer is simple `user_id` <> `userId`:

```
SELECT "Publication".*, 
       "user"."id" AS "user.id"
FROM 
    (SELECT "Publication"."club_id"  AS "clubId"
            ,"Publication"."user_id" AS "userId" 
      FROM "publication" AS "Publication" 
     WHERE "Publication"."club_id" = '1') AS "Publication" 
LEFT JOIN "user_account" AS "user" 
  ON "Publication"."userId" = "user"."id";
                    -- here use column's alias
```

Comment: Thanks, lad2025. I was looking to verify my understanding more than fixing the problem. I also did the change you proposed but wanted to be sure about the reasons.